# VS code terminal opens on each file save

Tags: visual-studio-code

My terminal opens on each save. I have this config.

```
"saveAndRun": {
        "commands": [
            {
                "cmd": "(cd ~/pay-backend/ && make format)"
            }
        ]
    },
```

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wk-j.save-and-run

Answer (score 0):

There's a setting for silent

````
"saveAndRun": {
        "commands": [
            {
                "cmd": "(cd ~/pay-backend/ && make format)",
                "silent": true
            }
        ]
    },
    ```
````